# Using logback with Akka

Tags: scala, akka, logback

I have some problems using Logback with my Akka (2.3.9) application. In order to log to stdout and in the logfile, I specified the logback.xml with all appenders:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds" debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level %logger{36} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>./akka.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>./akka.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level %logger{36} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="proc" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="akka.actor" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

After that I use logging in my Actor:

```
val log = Logging(context.system, classOf[MyActor])

override def receive: Receive = {
  case MyEvent(event) =>
     log.info("Message received for processing.")
}
```

The problem is, in SBT everything is fine: I can see all log events in the created logfile.

When I make JAR-File with sbt-assembly and start this jar file (java -jar event-assembly-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar). The app writes log entries to STDOUT but not in the file!

I have no idea how I can fix that. I tried with "lsof", the java process has no open log-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, how I found out, the sbt-assembly removed some logback-binaries from the result jar (it was settings in my Build.scala). After I changed the MergingStrategy to preserve the first logback occurrence in the result build, all works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong but you could do the following:

- Check if your logback.xml is in the jar-file
- Try to start your application with java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/logback.xml -jar event-assembly-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: I fixed the problem: the sbt-assembly removed some logback-binaries from the result jar. After I changed the MergingStrategy for logback all works correctly. Thank you.